# vscode extension doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Recently I created my first vscode extension to create react component very fast [vs-component-app](https://github.com/CVarisco/vs-component-app).
The problem is that in debugger mode it works very well and doesn't work in the published version.

Anyone could know why in the published version doesn't work ?

Comment: Try and post some error logs, would greatly help yourself and the people trying to help you.

Comment: Hi terrance00 how can I get error logs from published version of the extension ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the extension doesn't work because when vscode installed the extension he don't install all npm dependencies.
I don't know why he don't install all dependencies.
If someone know why, please tell me.

What I do:

- Added manually the missing dependencies on the package.json
- Updated npm version to v5.3